# Banned words checking algo

Tags: actionscript-3, algorithm

I am building a text chat system. I want to add the ability to check for banned words/phrases.

The only technique I can think of, and can't believe it could possibly be the best approach is to do a FOR loop through all the words and search for matches in the text. This seems like it would be unbelievably slow once lots of words are added.

I'm using AS3, but an answer in most any language would probably be  useful.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an AS3 dictionary or a dict in python and just check if the word is in the dict. there is no way I can see to not go over all the words.

Comment: YEah, After I posted this, I realized testing the words in the text against an array or dictionary would be better than testing the banned words individually. Thanks for confirming that idea Weasel

Comment: sure. dictionary is a better choice - its implemented as a hash-table and will work faster.

Comment: Check my answer - there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider concatenating all the entries in your Dictionary into a single RegExp, with which you have to parse the text only once.  I've done some testing, and it's going to be way faster than replacing word for word.

```
function censorWithDictionary ( dict:Dictionary, text:String ) : String {
    var reg : String = "";
    for (var key:Object in dict)
    {
        reg += reg=="" ? "" : "|";     // add an "or" for multiple search words
        reg += "\\b"+dict[key]+"\\b";  // only whole words
    }

    var regExp : RegExp = new RegExp ( reg, "gi" ); 
    return text.replace ( regExp, "----" );
}
```

Comment: looks nice! I will surely use this down the road

Comment: Thanks. This does look nice. Will it handle entries that are themselves regular expressions?

Comment: Partial ones, yes.  They will all be part of one large RegExp, so you can't do any fancy multiline or `^$` stuff.  But using metacharacters and/or character classes should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem - we run a gaming site and wanted to introduce a chat system which was not manually moderated. We went the "banned word" route and it's working really well.

I just counted them and we now have a list of (just) 79 banned words which originated from something I found on-line to which we have added words over time when chat messages crept through.

The way we check things is that we concatenate an entire chat message by removing all spaces and none alpha characters and then search for banned words in what's left.

The key decisions we made are:

1. Don't tell people why you rejected their messages
2. Don't let people post chat until you trust them a bit (on our site they have
   to have played 3 games)
3. 5 "Bad" messages and we automatically block you
4. We email a report out daily with all the chat which got through which we scan through
5. We allow other users to complain about posted messages - if that happens the message is automatically removed so we can check it later.

1+3+5 Hardly ever happen now and it works wonderfully even though - sometimes messages like

"I wish it was hot!"

Are rejected (the clue is the "sh" part of wish and "it") but even that doesn't happen often.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer, but comments are limited in length and there're  big issues here.

I believe you are fundamentally asking the wrong question!

Certainly dictionaries and blacklist would highlight words or phrases that *you* want to ban but would that list be acceptable to users of your system? Would there be text that users of your system find offensive but you do not. Who decides?

For example, would people living [here](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Dildo,+NL,+Canada&hl=en&ll=47.568679,-53.557062&spn=0.021282,0.027294&sll=36.949892,-122.431641&sspn=50.772725,55.898438&oq=dildo&hnear=Dildo,+Division+No.+1,+Newfoundland+and+Labrador,+Canada&t=h&z=15) have trouble or indeed people living [here](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=Scunthorpe,+North+Lincolnshire,+United+Kingdom&hl=en&sll=53.800651,-4.064941&sspn=19.143671,27.949219&geocode=FaayMQMdswP2_w&hnear=Scunthorpe,+North+Lincolnshire,+United+Kingdom&t=h&z=12). What if you supported [this football/soccer team](http://www.arsenal.com/home). [This person](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0911173/) probably never visits the UK.

Then you get into the issue of anagrams and slang. [FCUK](http://www.frenchconnection.com/index.aspx?mscsmigrated=true) is a high street brand in the UK (and elsewhere I'm sure). And then there's `pr0n` (no link!) or [NAMBLA](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/real-ultimate-programming-power.html).

The real question is - How do I stop people using the system from using language that is generally unacceptable? And that's more a design / social engineering problem than a programming problem. I don't think this site has word / phrase filtering and yet there's nothing here that would cause offense to anyone.

Here's an idea - let your users decide what is acceptable! Use a reputation based system. Allow users to vote up users who behave and vote down users that cause offense (with the option of allowing users to give feedback on the vote to give them a chance to mend their ways) and then have an option to filter out users with low / negative reputations.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment. This is an adult chat system for a client, so he wants to have absolute and specific control over what is and is not allowed.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss: I think you need to educate your client on how this is a not going to work - e.g. http://tonguetiedtim.com/slang-words-for-penis (NSFW) includes everyday words as well. For example, in the UK government, MPs can table a "Private Member's Bill" which would mean something else entirely in a different context.